# How to discover if another node have the same CordApp as I do?

Tags: corda

Is there anyway to know wheter or not another node in the network have the same CordApp as I do?

I'm worried about creating a network with a lot of nodes that are not related with a given CordApp that I have, but these same nodes have relation with another CordApp that I use. I think that we shouldn't need a network for each app.

This could be a problem in a scenario where I need to find a counterparty for my CordApp and I just want to list the nodes that have the same App as I do.

It would be good if I could use a method from  CordaRPCOps for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not exist as of Corda 3.2.

This is because it would cause privacy issues. Nodes may not want other nodes to know which CorDapps they are running.

Comment: I understand that seeing all the cordapps from another is a privacy issue, but from within a cordapp, I should be able to see what other nodes have the same cordapp.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion :) We would have to closely examine the various implications before adding such a feature to the platform.